# Jenkins agent templates lost after jenkins controller pod restarts

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, build, restart, agent

Setting up custom build agents using Kubernetes plugin on Jenkins represents a major issue.

Every time the Jenkins master node restarts, the custom agent templates defined in `Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Cloud > Kubernetes` are lost and we need to re-add them again.

I wonder what should be done to permanently save our custom agent templates especially that we regularly update Jenkins version and/or plugins.

Is there any solution for this ?

**What we tried:**

- Add custom agent templates under `Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Cloud > Kubernetes`
- Perform an action that requires Jenkins to restart.

**What is expected**

- Custom Jenkins agent templates still there.

**What we found**

- Jenkins custom agents are lost and need to be manually added again

Comment: Could you add some more information about `Jenkins` installation? You are doing it via `helm` or just raw `yaml`? For now it looks like there is no `persistent volume` and all data are stored in container so after restart/recreate they are lost.

Comment: Jenkins is installed via official helm chart with a PVC attached to the pod to store all jobs and configs. but surprisingly it does not store agent templates.

Comment: Could you let me know what is the version of `helm` chart that you are using to deploy your `Jenkins` instance so I can test it on my local environment?

Comment: I used multiple versions over the time, the latest use was the version 4.3.19

Comment: is there any suggestion ?

Comment: It looks like you will need to use configuration as a code since agent information is not save on PVC --> https://community.jenkins.io/t/manage-nodes-cloud/5094

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by adding my agent templates in podTemplates map in values like the following:

```
podTemplates:
customAgent: |
  - name: customAgent
    label: customAgent
    imagePullSecrets:
    - name: regcred
    containers:
      - name: agent
        image: agent_docker_image:0.1
        command: sleep
        args: 99999
        ttyEnabled: true
        workingDir: /home/jenkins/agent
```